# Convert YAML file to PHP File

Tags: php, yaml

I have a bunch of Yaml configuration files that I want to convert to straight PHP files so that the application does not have to process the Yaml files every time.

I know that there are a lot of libraries out there that will let you convert Yaml to a php array, but are there any libraries that will let you convert a yaml file to a php file?

The thing that makes this tricky is that converting a yaml file to php will usually produce a multidimensional array.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I just realized that the following code does what I think i need. Notice the second paramter in the print_r. Pretty cool...

```
$test = print_r($yaml, true);
file_put_contents('test.php', $test);
```

Comment: Any sample input/output?

Comment: If you have a YAML parser that gives you the data described in the YAML file as a PHP-ized data structure (i.e. arrays, strings, ints, etc.), you could use `var_export` on it... should work, shouldn't it? Or serialize it, e.g. with `serialize()`.

Comment: Just added an update that I think will solve this.

Comment: @Mike - `var_export` will be better because it's returning "parsable string representation of a variable". Look at my answer - posted before your edit.

Comment: `print_r` won't work. It's a somewhat human-readable representation, not PHP code (in fact, the output won't even parse).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a simple builtin to [export a PHP variable/array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php), which allows you to write a small script for that task:

```
$array = yaml_import(...);

$array = var_export($array, 1);
file_put_contens($fn, "<?php \$array = $array; ?>");
```

Answer (score 6):

**Just Try Using the Symfony YAML Component**

The Symfony2 Yaml component is very simple and consists of two main classes: one parses YAML strings (Parser), and the other dumps a PHP array to a YAML string (Dumper).

On top of these two classes, the Yaml class acts as a thin wrapper that simplifies common uses.

**Reading YAML Files**

The parse() method parses a YAML string and converts it to a PHP array:

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser;

$yaml = new Parser();

$value = $yaml->parse(file_get_contents('/path/to/file.yml'));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
file_put_contents('file.php', '<?php ' . var_export(your_yaml_parser_function_which_returns_php_array('file.yaml'), true));
```